# Are MOSFETs Sensitive to heat while soldering?

Tags: soldering, transistors

I'm soldering through the hole MOSFETs in to a PCB and I don't have a temperature controlled soldering iron. So will I need to heat sink the legs as I solder them to stop internal damage. I as this as bipolar transistors are damaged from heat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference in the structure of MOSFETs and BJT is that the former have a thin insulation layer. I don't know if this is easier damaged than the rest of the crystal when heating it. But I would *most strongly advise* you to get a temperature controlled soldering station. If you leave your iron unused for a minute the temperature will rise to levels components won't like.
Also, most likely a temp controlled station will have proper earthing which is even more important than temperature when soldering MOSFETs.

Answer (score 3):

They shouldn't need any special precautions when soldering, in terms of heat, compared to BJTs. They will be a lot more sensitive to ESD, so it might be a good idea to take precautions against that.

The data sheet should give you the maximum soldering temperature and time.